Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: SwiftData.SwiftDataError(_error: SwiftData.SwiftDataError._Error.loadIssueModelContainer)
I'm getting this error:

Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: SwiftData.SwiftDataError(_error: SwiftData.SwiftDataError._Error.loadIssueModelContainer)

I'm able to reproduce it in a new project this way:

Use SwiftData
Enable & select "My Mac (Designed for iPad)" as the run destination
Add "iCloud" capability; select iCloud Documents, CloudKit & one Container
Use a conditional inside the sheet
Use modelContext inside the sheet

E.g.:
@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var sharedModelContainer: ModelContainer = {
        let schema = Schema([
            Item.self,
        ])
        let modelConfiguration = ModelConfiguration(schema: schema, isStoredInMemoryOnly: false)

        do {
            return try ModelContainer(for: schema, configurations: [modelConfiguration])
        } catch {
            fatalError("Could not create ModelContainer: \(error)")
        }
    }()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .modelContainer(sharedModelContainer)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @State var showSheet = false

    var body: some View {
        Button {
            showSheet = true
        } label: {
            Text("Show Sheet")
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
            SheetView()
        }
    }
}

struct SheetView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    
    var body: some View {
        if true { // <--- any conditional in the sheet is causing the crash
            Text("Hello")
        }
    }
}


Where do you set up the model container?

@vadian I added the model container setup, it's the exact same as the default when I create a new Xcode project

It looks correct, although .modelContainer(for: Item.self) can replace the entire sharedModelContainer expression. Does the crash also occur when you disable CloudKit capabilities?

The crash only happens with the specific setup that I've outlined. Removing the if true fixes it, so does getting rid of the modelContext, putting the view outside of the sheet or as you mentioned disabling CloudKit.

Edit: I was getting this error because my SwiftData model's variables did not have an initial value (not just in init, but var x: String = "", etc.) or were not optional. Could this be the solution to your problem as well?

I'm assuming this might be a weird SwiftUI bug, I've reported it. As a workaround, passing the modelContext instead of using @Environment inside the sheet seems to avoid the issue:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showSheet = false
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext // <- use here

    var body: some View {
        Button {
            showSheet = true
        } label: {
            Text("Show Sheet")
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
            SheetView(modelContext: modelContext)
        }
    }
}

struct SheetView: View {
    var modelContext: ModelContext // <- pass as parameter instead
    
    var body: some View {
        if true {
            Text("Hello")
        }
    }
}

